# Unity3D (2D) - Make sure Item Dragged Is Top Item Visually

Tags: 2d, sprites, unity

I am using Unity 5 and making a 2D game in which many sprites will be stacked on top of each other and can then be moved by dragging. Sometimes when the users goes to drag from a pile, ones that aren't on the top are dragged instead. Is there any way to make sure that the one that is dragged is the one on top? Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you had some of your code.

Comment: This depends on how you have implemented the select and drag behaviour. It sounds like Sorting Layers aren't the problem - you already have them stacked correctly. So it is likely to do with your selection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: move them a tiny bit on the z-axis, or whichever axis the camera is oriented on. Then make it so that they block raycasting to things behind them - putting the sprites at minimally different positions on the z-axis should allow for the colliders to block the raycasting to anything behind it.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this tutorial on [Sprite Sorting Layers](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sorting-layers)

In short, you can use the [Sprite Renderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html) component and modify the layer properties to achieve the effect you want.